# Detect with JQuery when a select changes

Tags: jquery, html, jqgrid, triggers

I have a Jqgrid which dynamically generates selects like this:

```
    <select id="won" style="width: 65px;">
       <option value="">-WON?</option>
       <option value="1" selected>Bet1</option>
       <option value="2" >Bet2</option>
       <option value="3" >Bet3</option>
    </select>
```

Each one have a different selected option. I would like to detect when one select changes so I can save it in my database.

I'm trying with:

```
         $('#won').change(function(){
               alert("PROBANDO");
          });
```

But is not working at all.

Answer (score 98, accepted):

The problem is that the select are created dynamically, then you need to use `.on()`

try this:

```
         $(document).on('change','#won',function(){
               alert("PROBANDO");
          });
```

Comment: How could I detect which won is changing? I should name them different?

Comment: usually inside html id are unique! is very important this rule. if you can create more select with different id like won1, won2. If you can't use classes like won1, won2 but I really advise you to have unique id inside your html @user2876368

Comment: $(this).find("option:selected").attr('value') tells you the new "won value" if it is what you are looking for ...

Comment: what are you talking about? OP ask which of the select are changed not the current selected option @CorinneKubler

Comment: I will :) How can I call this function with dinamically "wons" (won320, won896, won99) ??
var x = 0;
$(document).on('change','#won'+x,function(){
               alert("PROBANDO");
          });

Comment: you can do this: $(document).on('change','[id^="won"]',function(){ alert("PROBANDO"); }); or something similar, it would be that find changing of input that id starts with string "won" @user2876368

Comment: oups so $(this) will give the select which changed isn't it ?

Comment: I was stucked into this for hours... Thanks +1

Answer (score 37):

This should work, be sure you did not forget `$(document).ready(function() {`

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    $('#won').change(function(){
        alert( $(this).find("option:selected").attr('value') );       
    });
 });
```

Comment: Found this most usefull

Comment: this is waiting for the document to be ready, but if #won is generated dynamically this will fail. The correct answer is to listen for events at a stable, non generated html node, and check the event came from the correct child node, in this case the stable node is "document" and "#won" is the child.